# Installing RGtk2 on macOS Sierra (Version 10.12.4) and R version 3.4.0

Tags: r

When I try to install the package RGtk2 I get the following error:

```html
> install.packages("RGtk2")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘RGtk2’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘RGtk2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RGtk2_2.20.33.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2792938 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘RGtk2’ ...
** package ‘RGtk2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for INTROSPECTION... no
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: GTK version 2.8.0 required
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RGtk2’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/RGtk2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RGtk2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/private/var/folders/m4/l02774c51vx71qt6_wdq59lw0000gn/T/Rtmpa7sxIS/downloaded_packages’
>
```

I am running macOS Sierra (Version 10.12.4) and R version 3.4.0.

Comment: You don't have GTK installed. These instructions may help: https://gist.github.com/sebkopf/9405675

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have R and RStudio installed already. If not, install it. Then do the following.

1) Install [XQuartz](https://dl.bintray.com/xquartz/downloads/XQuartz-2.7.11.dmg)

2) Install [GTK 2.24.17-X11](http://r.research.att.com/libs/GTK_2.24.17-X11.pkg)

3) Download [cairoDevice](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/cairoDevice_2.24.tar.gz) and [RGtk2](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/RGtk2_2.20.33.tar.gz)

4) From terminal run `R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/cairoDevice_2.24.tar.gz`

5) Install *Homebrew* for Mac.

6) From terminal type the following commands:

`brew uninstall cairo --ignore-dependencies
brew install --with-x11 cairo`

7) Type `brew edit gtk+` in terminal and scroll to def install section and edit the reference with **quartz** to (press i to edit and to save and exit, press escape key and type colon (shift+ semi colon key). Then type wq.)

`"--with-gdktarget=x11",
"--enable-x11-backend"`

8) Then type `brew install --build-from-source --verbose gtk+` in the same terminal window.

9) Then type `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gtk+-2.0.pc:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig`

10) Type `R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/RGtk2_2.20.33.tar.gz` from the same terminal window.

Hopefully it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have GTK installed in your system (outside of R). You can try an install from the GTK package in the ../libs/ directory here:

```
http://r.research.att.com/libs/
```

Probably need XQuartz, Xcode of the proper version for your macOS version and the correct Command Line Tools first. The download and install code for the bash-install are at the bottom of that /libs/ page.

Answer (score 0):

when I tried to install RGtk2 this comes up... I checked `which gcc` and it shows a c compiler. why does it say that C compiler is not working?

```
$ R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/RGtk2_2.20.33.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘RGtk2’ ...
** package ‘RGtk2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for INTROSPECTION... no
checking for GTK... yes
checking for GTHREAD... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/xh/kw0cr4xj52zd9pd8t46d6xwh0000gn/T/RtmpnYEC6D/R.INSTALL13a7b3357df80/RGtk2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RGtk2’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/RGtk2’
```

Answer (score -1):

Following the directions on this website will likely be helpful: https://gist.github.com/sebkopf/9405675.

Be sure to read the additional conversations after the post for useful modifications.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, firstly thank you for taking the time to answer. Please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read [answer] to create helpful answers and add to the community.

Comment: Link only answer