# Install RGtk2 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and R Version 3.4.1

Tags: r, gtk, homebrew, macos-sierra, rattle

My ultimate goal is to install the rattle package in R, and to do that, I need to install the dependency RGtk2.

This question is similar to [Installing RGtk2 on macOS Sierra (Version 10.12.4) and R version 3.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013379/installing-rgtk2-on-macos-sierra-version-10-12-4-and-r-version-3-4-0)
But I have gtk installed. 
This question is similar to [R In install.packages("RGtk2") : fatal error: 'gdk/gdkx.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364313/r-in-install-packagesrgtk2-fatal-error-gdk-gdkx-h-file-not-found)
but that question is still open, and I'm hoping someone can shine more light on this issue.

The error I'm having is below:

```
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘RGtk2’ ...
** package ‘RGtk2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for INTROSPECTION... no
checking for GTK... yes
checking for GTHREAD... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
```

...

```
Rgtk.c:7:10: fatal error: 'gdk/gdkx.h' file not found
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
```

I've seen a solution to force or ignore gdk/gdkx.h, but it seems fishy to me.

To install rattle, I've taken the following steps. Following this string, [R 3.0 and GTK+ / RGTK2 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868860/r-3-0-and-gtk-rgtk2-error), I tried downloading Simon Urbanek's library from  http://r.research.att.com/#other, using the GTK_2.24.17-X11.pkg but it didn't work.

From that same question, I also installed homebrew from brew.sh just by copying the command they give.

```
brew install gtk+
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
R CMD INSTALL /Users/joshualamstein/Downloads/RGtk2_2.20.33.tar
```

Which lead to the results I have now, and my question. My ultimate goal is to install the rattle package in R, and to do that, I need to install the dependency RGtk2. Any help you have would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This has been a regular issue on MacOS. One new solution is to run rattle on MacOS in a Docker container. I've created an image for rattle available from docker hub. Instructions also available there: https://hub.docker.com/r/kayon/rattle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution posted by zhiyzou here worked for me with Sierra 10.12.6 and R 3.4.2: https://gist.github.com/zhiyzuo/a489ffdcc5da87f28f8589a55aa206dd

Then be sure to restart Rstudio, or launch through XQuartz.